# Comparing the performance of two models

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, model

Suppose that I have a set of data sets $(m_i)$. Each of this data set $m_i$ is related to 
a parameter $\hat{\theta}_i$ that I know. Then I have two models providing me HPDs intervals for each $\theta_i|m_i$. I want to assess/compare the performance of the two models. Obvisouly I can simply look how many of the $\hat{\theta}_i$ falls in the intervals for both method but this seems to be a very rough characterisation (the two models can give identical scores but HPDs of very different nature) and I wonder is there any more specific tools to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what the answer is and you are are calculating highest posterior density (HPD) intervals I would say that choosing the method that returns the narrowest interval would be a starting point in selecting the better method, especially since HPD intervals do not have to be symmetric.  Of of course you could look at a criteria like BIC, since you are doing this from a Bayesian perspective, but since you are talking about $\theta_i|m_i$ when not try using Bayes factors to compare models? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor  The way you problem is set up I think it would lend itself greatly to Bayes factors.  Lastly, I think seeing how well calibrated your model is (i.e.,  finding the proportion of times the $θ^i$ falls in the intervals) is also a very good idea.  So, bottom line if you have the time I think all of those aforementioned criteria are worth looking into.  Also, have you considered trying some sensitivity analysis for your prior choice?

Comment: Thanks! My point is that for one of the model, I cannot access the model but only to its "output" (thus n% interval). So BIC/sensitivity analysis/Bayes Factor seem not possible. The calibration study (with different levels for the HPD interval) seems a good choice. Have you any guidelines or recommendations to perform such an analysis ? Thanks a lot.